# JAXB @XmlElementWrapper ArrayList size zero

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an XML to load with JAXB. It load correctly, except that getEffectSettings() size is 0 when it should show 2 because I have two 'effect-setting' in the 'settings-list' element. Any ideas? I'm able to load and print the Effect's target attribute and the effects are shown as it should except this variable.

The XML:

```
<item:item xmlns:item="http://www.swordsandsorcery.com/item" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.swordsandsorcery.com/item ../schema.xsd">
    <item:id>1</item:id>
    <item:name>Laxi's epic</item:name>
    <item:type>ONE_HANDED_AXES</item:type>
    <item:usable>true</item:usable>
    <item:use-effect-list>
        <item:effect target="com.xyz.HealEffect">
            <item:settings-list>
                <item:effect-setting>
                    <item:setting-name>amount</item:setting-name>
                    <item:setting-value>10</item:setting-value>
                </item:effect-setting>
                <item:effect-setting>
                    <item:setting-name>xyz</item:setting-name>
                    <item:setting-value>10</item:setting-value>
                </item:effect-setting>
            </item:settings-list>
        </item:effect>
    </item:use-effect-list>
    <item:weight>5</item:weight>
    <item:combat-modifiers>
        <item:modifier>
            <item:attribute>ATTACK</item:attribute>
            <item:amount>1</item:amount>
        </item:modifier>
        <item:modifier>
            <item:attribute>DEFENSE</item:attribute>
            <item:amount>1</item:amount>
        </item:modifier>
        <item:modifier>
            <item:attribute>LIFE</item:attribute>
            <item:amount>3</item:amount>
        </item:modifier>
    </item:combat-modifiers>
    <item:general-modifiers>
        <item:modifier>
            <item:attribute>STRENGTH</item:attribute>
            <item:amount>1</item:amount>
        </item:modifier>
    </item:general-modifiers>
    <item:skill-modifiers>
        <item:modifier>
            <item:attribute>TWO_HANDED_CRUSHING_WEAPONS</item:attribute>
            <item:amount>2</item:amount>
        </item:modifier>
    </item:skill-modifiers>
    <item:basic-modifiers>
        <item:modifier>
            <item:attribute>MOVEMENT</item:attribute>
            <item:amount>1</item:amount>
        </item:modifier>
    </item:basic-modifiers>
    <item:general-requirements>
        <item:requirement>
            <item:attribute>DEXTERITY</item:attribute>
            <item:amount>100</item:amount>
        </item:requirement>
    </item:general-requirements>
</item:item>
```

The nodes in path:

RawItemDefinition.java (root node):
    package com.morethanheroic.swords.item.service.domain;

```
import com.morethanheroic.swords.effect.domain.Effect;
import com.morethanheroic.swords.item.domain.ItemType;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

@XmlRootElement(name = "item")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class RawItemDefinition {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private ItemType type;
    private boolean usable;
    private int weight;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "use-effect-list")
    @XmlElement(name = "effect")
    private ArrayList<Effect> effectList;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "basic-modifiers")
    @XmlElement(name = "modifier")
    private ArrayList<BasicAttributeModifierDefinition> basicModifiers;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "combat-modifiers")
    @XmlElement(name = "modifier")
    private ArrayList<CombatAttributeModifierDefinition> combatModifiers;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "general-modifiers")
    @XmlElement(name = "modifier")
    private ArrayList<GeneralAttributeModifierDefinition> generalModifiers;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "skill-modifiers")
    @XmlElement(name = "modifier")
    private ArrayList<SkillAttributeModifierDefinition> skillModifiers;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "basic-requirements")
    @XmlElement(name = "requirement")
    private ArrayList<BasicAttributeRequirementDefinition> basicRequirements;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "combat-requirements")
    @XmlElement(name = "requirement")
    private ArrayList<CombatAttributeRequirementDefinition> combatRequirements;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "general-requirements")
    @XmlElement(name = "requirement")
    private ArrayList<GeneralAttributeRequirementDefinition> generalRequirements;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "skill-requirements")
    @XmlElement(name = "requirement")
    private ArrayList<SkillAttributeRequirementDefinition> skillRequirements;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public ItemType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public boolean isUsable() {
        return usable;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "RawItemDefinition -> [id: " + id + " name: " + name + "]";
    }

    public List<BasicAttributeModifierDefinition> getBasicModifiers() {
        return basicModifiers;
    }

    public List<CombatAttributeModifierDefinition> getCombatModifiers() {
        return combatModifiers;
    }

    public List<GeneralAttributeModifierDefinition> getGeneralModifiers() {
        return generalModifiers;
    }

    public List<SkillAttributeModifierDefinition> getSkillModifiers() {
        return skillModifiers;
    }

    public List<SkillAttributeRequirementDefinition> getSkillRequirements() {
        return skillRequirements;
    }

    public List<BasicAttributeRequirementDefinition> getBasicRequirements() {
        return basicRequirements;
    }

    public List<CombatAttributeRequirementDefinition> getCombatRequirements() {
        return combatRequirements;
    }

    public List<GeneralAttributeRequirementDefinition> getGeneralRequirements() {
        return generalRequirements;
    }

    public List<AttributeRequirementDefinition> getAllRequirements() {
        List<AttributeRequirementDefinition> list = new ArrayList<>();

        if (basicRequirements != null) {
            list.addAll(basicRequirements);
        }
        if (combatRequirements != null) {
            list.addAll(combatRequirements);
        }
        if (generalRequirements != null) {
            list.addAll(generalRequirements);
        }
        if (skillRequirements != null) {
            list.addAll(skillRequirements);
        }

        return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
    }

    public ArrayList<Effect> getEffectList() {
        return effectList;
    }
}
```

Effect.java:
    package com.morethanheroic.swords.effect.domain;

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Effect {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String target;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "settings-list")
    @XmlElement(name = "effect-setting")
    private ArrayList<EffectSetting> effectSettings;

    public String getTarget() {
        return target;
    }

    public ArrayList<EffectSetting> getEffectSettings() {
        return effectSettings;
    }
}
```

EffectSetting.java:

```
package com.morethanheroic.swords.effect.domain;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class EffectSetting {

    @XmlElement(name = "setting-name")
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "setting-value")
    private String value;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

The unmarshaller I use is this:

```
package com.morethanheroic.swords.definition.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class XMLDefinitionLoader {

    private static final SchemaFactory schemaFactory =  SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public List loadDefinitions(Class clazz, String resourcePath, String schemaPath) throws JAXBException, IOException, SAXException {
        return unmarshallTargetFiles(buildUnmarshaller(clazz, schemaPath), getTargetFiles(resourcePath));
    }

    private ArrayList unmarshallTargetFiles(Unmarshaller unmarshaller, File[] files) throws JAXBException {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (File file : files) {
            list.add(unmarshaller.unmarshal(file));
        }

        return list;
    }

    private File[] getTargetFiles(String resourcePath) throws IOException {
        return applicationContext.getResource(resourcePath).getFile().listFiles();
    }

    private Unmarshaller buildUnmarshaller(Class clazz, String schemaPath) throws IOException, SAXException, JAXBException {
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz).createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setSchema(buildSchema(schemaPath));

        return unmarshaller;
    }

    private Schema buildSchema(String schemaPath) throws IOException, SAXException {
        return schemaFactory.newSchema(applicationContext.getResource(schemaPath).getFile());
    }
}
```

And this is how I try to access the effects:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() throws Exception {
    List<RawItemDefinition> rawItemDefinitionList = xmlDefinitionLoader.loadDefinitions(RawItemDefinition.class, "classpath:data/item/definition/", "classpath:data/item/schema.xsd");

    for (RawItemDefinition rawItemDefinition : rawItemDefinitionList) {
        if(rawItemDefinition.getEffectList() != null) {
            System.out.println("EFFECT: "+rawItemDefinition.getEffectList().get(0).getTarget());
            System.out.println("EFFECT: "+rawItemDefinition.getEffectList().get(0).getEffectSettings().size());
        }

        itemDefinitionMap.put(rawItemDefinition.getId(), new ItemDefinition(rawItemDefinition));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you provide your code to call `getEffectSettings()` and how the unmarshalling is done (by hand or any framework ?).

**UPDATE**

Have you tried adding `@XmlRootElement` to your `EffectSetting` class ?

**UPDATE 2**

As you found yourself, check packages of your classes :

> The `Effect` and `EffectSetting` was in an other package than `RawItemData` and I added the `package-info.java` to the `RawItemData`'s package. After adding it to the `Effect`'s package it's started working.

Comment: Thanks for writing, I added the required info.

Comment: I found out something also, when I use @XmlElementWrapper(name = "settings-list")  @XmlAnyElement instead of @XmlElementWrapper(name = "settings-list") @XmlElement(name = "effect-setting") it finds 2 entries but when I trying to access them I get an exception like this: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to com.morethanheroic.swords.effect.domain.EffectSetting

Comment: Yes, I tried adding @XmlRootElement to both Effect and EffectSetting already sadly.

Comment: You could create a list with 2 entries in the Java and marshall it to see the XML generated. It should give you some hints of what is the problem.

Another way is, when getting a list of 2 `ElementNSImpl ` you could try to print them to understand the problem.

Comment: Ohh god, I found it.... The Effect and EffectSetting was in an other package than RawItemData and I added the package-info.java to the RawItemData's package. After adding it to the Effect's package it's started working magically. If you add this to your answer i'll accept it for you because you helped me a lot not to give up. :) I'm not even mad at the end of this, just feeling a little bit of bitter emptiness towards JaxB...